# The order of the user input names and weights are all over the place and not ascending. Why is the doubly linked list not linking properly?

Tags: c++, output, doubly-linked-list

The program is supposed to accept user input names and weights on alternating separate lines and while those are being input, it should be building the doubly linked list in order of ascending names for one pointer and ascending weights for the other pointer. If input name already ordered they print fine, but the weights are messed up and if I input out of order its a disaster. I have tried writing it all down on paper to get a visual of what the computer would be doing, but I cant figure out why this not working.
user input:
jim
150
tom
212
micheal
174

output:
jim
212
tom
1
micheal
1

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    //Node class for the linked list
    class Node
    {
    public:
        string name = " ";
        int weight = 1;
        Node *nextName;
        Node *nextWeight;

        Node();
    };

    Node::Node()
    {
        nextName = NULL;
        nextWeight = NULL;
    }

    void namePrint(Node *nHead, int counter1);
    void weightPrint(Node *wHead, int counter2);
    void lister(string name, int weight, Node *builder, Node *nHead, Node *wHead);
    Node namePlace(string name, Node *builder, Node *next, Node *nHead);
    void weightPlace(int weight, Node *builder, Node *next, Node *wHead);


    int main()
    {
        Node *builder;
        Node *nHead;
        Node *wHead;
        string name;
        int weight;
        int counter = 0;

        builder = new Node;
        nHead = builder;
        wHead = builder;


        cout << "Please enter names and weights on alternating seperate lines." <<
            "\n When you are ready to show the results please enter: \n         'print by name' or 'print by weight'" <<
            "\n enter 'end program' to end the program" << endl;

        do
        {
            if (counter > 0)
            {
                cin.ignore();
            }

            getline(cin, name);

            if (name == "end program")
            {
                system("PAUSE");
                return 0;
            }
            else if (name == "print by name")
            {
                namePrint(nHead, counter);
            }
            else if (name == "print by weight")
            {
                weightPrint(wHead, counter);
            }
            else
            {
                cin >> weight;
                if (counter > 0)
                {
                    lister(name, weight, builder, nHead, wHead);
                }
                else
                {
                    builder->name = name;
                    builder->weight = weight;
                    nHead = builder;
                    wHead = builder;
                }
                counter++;
            }

        } while (name != "end program");
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    void lister(string name, int weight, Node *builder, Node *nHead, Node *wHead)
    {
        Node *next = nHead;

        namePlace(name, builder, next, nHead);

        next = wHead;

        weightPlace(weight, builder, next, wHead);

    }

    Node namePlace(string name, Node *builder, Node *next, Node *nHead)
    {
        bool spot = false;
        while (spot == false)
        {
            if (name < nHead->name)
            {
                builder = new Node;
                builder->name = name;
                builder->nextName = nHead;
                nHead->nextName = builder;
                spot = true;
                return *builder;
            }
             else if (name < next->name || next->nextName == NULL)
            {
                builder = new Node;
                builder->name = name;
                builder->nextName = next->nextName;
                next->nextName = builder;
                spot = true;
                return *builder;
            }
            else if (name > next->name)
            {
                next = next->nextName;
                //return namePlace(name, builder, next, nHead);
            }
        }
    }

    void weightPlace(int weight, Node *builder, Node *next, Node *wHead)
    {
        bool spot = false;
        while (spot == false)
        {
            if (weight < wHead->weight)
            {
                builder->weight = weight;
                builder->nextWeight = wHead;
                wHead = builder;
                spot = true;
            }
            else if (weight < next->weight || next->nextWeight == NULL)
            {
                builder->weight = weight;
                builder->nextWeight = next->nextWeight;
                next->nextWeight = builder;
                spot = true;
            }
            else if (weight > next->weight)
            {
                next = next->nextWeight;
                //weightPlace(weight, builder, next, wHead);
            }
        }
    }

    void namePrint(Node *nHead, int counter1)
    {
        Node *next = nHead;
        for (int i = 0; i < counter1; i++)
        {
            cout << next->name << endl;
            cout << next->weight << endl;

            next = next->nextName;
        }
    }

    void weightPrint(Node *wHead, int counter2)
    {
        Node *next = wHead;
        for (int i = 0; i < counter2; i++)
        {
            cout << next->name << endl;
            cout << next->weight << endl;

            next = next->nextName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. You are trying to do too much at once. Write the linked list. Test the snot out of it so you know that all of its functionality works correctly. Then write code that uses the linked list. If you write everything at once, you test everything at once and you have a much larger search area to have to hunt bugs. 2. Get familiar with the debugging software that came with your development environment. A debugger is the best programming productivity tool you are likely to ever find.

Comment: That's not a doubly linked list. I suggest that you read more about what a doubly linked list is before writing any more code. Then throw away what you've got and start over.